# Connect a loop of edges to a point

Tags: faces, edges, looping

I have N edges forming a loop, and the edges are not coplanar.  I want to fill this N-gon with a face, but that does not make sense (at least such a face will not be 3d-printable) since the points are not coplanar.  So selecting all N edges and then pressing F, though it seems to show a face in Blender, is not the solution for me.  So I'm content with simply choosing a new point that is roughly at the center of this loop, and then forming N triangular faces with the N edges.  This will succeed in closing the loop with a "face".  Can someone explain how this is done?

Of course, if someone can explain how I can nudge the N points to become exactly coplanar (they are almost coplanar right now, but not exactly), then of course filling the N-gon with a single face would be acceptable and a more clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple of things:

- In edit mode, select the Ngon, and triangulate it. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> )
- Or Poke the face to create a fan (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
- Select all the faces you would like to flatten, for an average, or the one you would like the others to match, and create a new Transform Orientation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>). Perhaps give it a name. Then, making sure you're in your new orientation,  with the faces you want to be planar selected, scale them to 0 along your newly created Z-axis (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>)